# WP Masterslider PHP shortcode in Timber/Twig?

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, timber, masterslider

I have `<?php masterslider(1); ?>` and I need that to render in a .twig file, can anyone let me know the formatting for timber to get this function to work.

Answer (score 3):

With Timber you can call functions in your Twig files:

```
{{ function('function_to_call', 'param_1', 'param_2', '…' ) }}
```

The first argument will be the name of the function to call, the following arguments will be all the parameters you want/need to pass to that function.

You could translate your function `<?php masterslider(1); ?>` to `{{ function('masterslider', 1) }}` if you want to use it in a Twig file.

To learn more about calling functions in Twig when using Timber, refer to the [the Timber documentation on functions](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/functions/).